# Django regex catching empty or space character

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

Why is the following regular expression in Python in Django matching '/' with views.v?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.i, name='i'), 
    url(r'^(?P<p>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.v, name='v'),
]
```

So a url of domain/a or domain/bcde, and so on matches views.v; a url of domain/ should match views.i, but there is a "NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for '/' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found" error. That means '/' is matching views.v?

Anybody knows?

Comment: Can you provide an example of input that doesn't work how you expect it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Reverse for '/'` suggests that you have `{% url '/' %}` in your code. That doesn't make sense - `/` is already a url, so there is no need to reverse it.

You should use the *name* of the url pattern with the url tag, for example:

```
{% url 'i' %}
```